# I want to buy a used aria stg series guitar electric

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

[image][image]I'm considering buying a used guitar, like the one pictured. What are the things that I should test on it to see if it's a good guitar or not?
Thing like the physical shape, the strings, etc.

Comment: Just to be prepared for future questions, do you plan to post every other guitar you find online until someone says "Yeah, get that one!" ? :P (in reference to https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/96254/what-is-the-name-of-this-guitar)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no it was just these two.. But there would be a problem if i do so?

Comment: I don't know. My comment was mostly a joke :)

Comment: Answered in 'What to look out for when buying a super cheap used guitar. All points covered there. So - a dupe?

Comment: There are plenty of gear forums where you can discuss your GAS, but the point is that you come in with a general question and hopefully it's already been answered. "Is this specific used guitar worth buying?" is not going to be useful to another person unless they come asking about the exact same instrument.

Comment: There are plenty of gear forums where you can discuss your GAS, but the point is that you come in with a general question and hopefully it's already been answered. "Is this specific used guitar worth buying?" is not going to be useful to another person unless they come asking about the exact same instrument.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll want to look down the length of the neck of the guitar to see if it is warped or twisted, a little bow in the neck can be corrected but a twisted neck will need replacement. Next you'll need to examine the bridge to make sure all parts are functional there. This includes the whammy bar mechanism located under the plate on the backside of the guitar. Make sure the springs that hold this mechanism together are in good working order. Next you'll want to play something on it. Plug it in, turn on the amp and listen to see if you like the sound of it, fool with the pickup switch to make sure it is working and listen to the pickups to make sure they work and see if you like the sound of them. Next, you'll need to decide if you like the feel of the guitar when you play it. That's pretty important because if you don't like the feel of it, you probably won't want to play it very often. Aria has made some high quality guitars, and some that are also unimpressive, so you'll need to decide for yourself if this is the guitar you've always wanted to own. Best of luck!